# How to read csv file in bseindia.com site using php

Tags: php, csv, curl

http://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/MarketWatch.aspx

on this page you can see an option to download csv file.

[image]

But can't get the URL of that file.
I wanted to read the file in PHP using curl or any other method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the source, you will see that it isn't just an url assigned to the image. It is `input type="image"`which means you need to send the POST with attributes (e.g. cURL).

Comment: How do I get that POST data?

Comment: You can see what POST attributes are sent to the browser using extension Live HTTP headers or something like that. Then open it, click the excel icon and you will see what is sent. Then use it in cURL process like that `curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'test=something&test2=something');`

Comment: But on clicking an open/save window will appear. From this how do I get that POST data

Comment: When you open the Live HTTP Headers extension you will still get the POST you sent.

Comment: Checked the POST by myself and the POST you need to insert in cURL is here: http://pastebin.com/ikrwjc3P